# How is the statement $0<(\lambda y_{1}-x_{1})^2 + (\lambda y_{2}-x_{2})^2$ expressing the following two conditions?

Tags: logic, proof-writing

Condition 1: $y_{1}$ and $y_{2}$ are not both $0$.

Condition 2: There is no $\lambda$ such that $x_{1} = \lambda y_{1}$ and $x_{2} = \lambda y_{2}$.

I could express Condition 1 as: $0<y_{1} + y_{2}$

I could express Condition 2 as: $0<(\lambda y_{1}-x_{1}) + (\lambda y_{2}-x_{2})$

It's not clear to me how to combine both expressions into one that simultaneously expresses both conditions, but the book I have (Spivak Calculus ch1 problem 19(a)) expresses it like this:

$0<(\lambda y_{1}-x_{1})^2 + (\lambda y_{2}-x_{2})^2$

I am having trouble seeing how this expresses both conditions and how one might arrive at such an expression from the individual conditions.

Really, I am trying to work backwards to understand the book's statement.  Seems the way I expressed my conditions should have used $0 \ne$ instead of $0<$ but I am just trying to retrofit the book's statement.  Definitely confused here.

Comment: "I could express Condition 1 as: $0<y_1+y_2$." Careful: what if $y_1$ or $y_2$ is negative? Instead of your inequality, consider $0 < y_1^2 + y_2^2$. This guarantees that the $y_i$ are not both zero (and it covers the case where they might be neegative). From there, the expression from the book is an elaboration that also guarantees condition 2.

Comment: Ah thanks!  That ought to help me understand the rest.

Comment: Let $y_{1} = y_{2} = 0$, then the book's expression becomes $0<(-x_{1})^2 +(- x_{2})^2$.   So the only way to make this false is to let $x_{1} = x_{2} = 0$.  So doesn't this allow me to violate the conditions?

Comment: In that case, since the $x_i$ and $y_i$ are all zero, you will have $x_1 = \lambda y_1$ and $x_2 = \lambda y_2$ for all $\lambda$. This violates condition 2.

Comment: Here's a bit more explanation: as mentioned, condition 1 can be written $0 < y_1^2 + y_2^2$. Condition 2 can be reworded to say "There is no $\lambda$ such that $x_1 - \lambda y_1$ and $x_2 - \lambda y_2$ are both $0$." This is similar to the first condition, so we can use the same technique: $0 < (x_1 - \lambda y_1)^2 + (x_2 - \lambda y_2)^2$. We could combine these two inequalities thus: $0 < y_1^2 + y_2^2 + (x_1 - \lambda y_1)^2 + (x_2 - \lambda y_2)^2$. The only way that the right-hand side would equal $0$ would be if $y_1, y_2, x_1 - \lambda y_1$, and $x_1 - \lambda y_2$ were all $0$.

Comment: (cont'd) That long inequality would therefore cover the two conditions, and you could stop there. However, by a happy coincidence, the inequality for condition 2 actually includes condition 1 (as explained in the earlier comments above), so we can use just that inequality, avoiding the need for the longer one.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed explanation, that helped clear things up.  This also helped me to understand that the book's expression entails a third condition: $x_{1}$ and $x_{2}$ are not both $0$.